# Как получить конечную ссылку после редиректа?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

не могу получить последнюю ссылку после редиректа по этому адресу: https://z1.fm/download/4866738?play=on

Можно ли с этим как-то справиться и получить конечную ссылку ?

Я уже перепробовал и через curl использовать `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`

Но результата никакого. Вот мой код:

```
function get($url) {

        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208');
        echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $ss = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $ss;
}


$a = get('https://m.z1.fm/download/21970909?play=on');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вот только он возвращает первую ссылку, вот мой код https://pastebin.com/F47z6CV7